# Robot.txt 404 - Page not found - Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, robots.txt, nuxtjs3

Hello everyone I'm currently using Nuxt3 and I face some error when accessing the robot.txt

Here's the [Robot.txt](https://github.com/nuxt-community/robots-module) module that I'm using

My **nuxt.config.ts**

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    imports: {
        autoImport: true
    },

    modules: [
        '@unocss/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/robots',
    ],

    robots: {
        UserAgent: '*',
        Disallow: ''
    }
})
```

After that I run generate and preview script from **package.json**

Here's my **package.json**

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/json": "^2.1.112",
    "@unocss/nuxt": "^0.45.22",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/robots": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

After running the preview command/script It says in terminal **INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:3000.**

When I click on this address my app will shown on browser but when I go to this address
**http://localhost:3000/robot.txt** It's redirect to 404 page

Comment: The URL should be `robots.txt` not `robot.txt`.

Comment: @some-user It's redirect on 404 page with `robots.txt`

Comment: Also, you may not need a module at all here, you could put your `robots.txt` file directly into `/public` IMO.

Answer (score 0):

for nuxt 3 you should use nuxtjs/robots@3.0.0

e.g:

```
npm install @nuxtjs/robots@3.0.0
```